# Django custom form rendering

Tags: python, django, forms

When i put { form } in some template it renders this:

```
 <tr><th></th><td><input type="text" name="login" maxlength="10" /></td></tr>
<tr><th></th><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
<tr><th></th><td><input type="text" name="password" maxlength="10" /></td></tr>
```

but what if I do not need tr,th,td,p tags? this is what I want.

```
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Имя пользователя"/>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently seeing is the output of form.as_table, which gives you the form rendered as tr elements that you insert into a set of  tags.  You'll want to check out [Customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) in the django docs to make them do exactly what you want them to do.  That link walk you through it with examples.

To just get the input widgets, iterate through the form and only insert the field itself:

```
 <form action="" method="get">
     {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
     {% endfor %}
 </form>
```